# Heroku Node app keeps crashing

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, pm2

I have an Express app hosted on Heroku. Locally it runs just fine, but keeps crashing on Heroku. Every time I go to it I get the 'Application Error' page.

[image: application error page]

I double checked all environment variables and they seem ok.

The Heroku logs don't exactly offer much help:

```
2017-04-16T23:02:49.001768+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed 
to starting
2017-04-16T23:02:52.072906+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
command `npm run start`
2017-04-16T23:02:56.042611+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-04-16T23:02:56.042628+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-app@0.0.1 start /app
2017-04-16T23:02:56.042629+00:00 app[web.1]: > node bin/app
2017-04-16T23:02:56.042630+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-04-16T23:02:57.200912+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting 
to crashed
2017-04-16T23:02:57.201454+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed 
to starting
2017-04-16T23:02:57.192198+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-04-16T23:03:00.981528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with 
command `npm run start`
2017-04-16T23:03:04.312475+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-04-16T23:03:04.312489+00:00 app[web.1]: > my-app@0.0.1 start /app
2017-04-16T23:03:04.312490+00:00 app[web.1]: > node bin/app
2017-04-16T23:03:04.312491+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-04-16T23:03:06.093211+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-04-16T23:03:06.112842+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting 
to crashed
```

So then I tried starting the app manually:

```
$ heroku run bash
...
$ npm run start
```

I got no errors. I'm using the pm2 process manager, so I checked it to see if the app is running and it seems like it is:

```
$ node_modules/.bin/pm2 list
...
```

[image: pm2 output]

But then when I go to open my app I get the same 'Application error' page as before.

'heroku restart' doesn't help. It just crashes again every time.

The only difference between my local environment and Heroku (as far as I can tell at least...) is that locally I have a file from which I'm reading a RSA private key, and on Heroku that key is read from the environment.

Edit: As requested, here's my Procfile:

```
web: npm run start
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does the RSA private key do ? Did you follow Heroku's instructions to deploy your app ? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction

Comment: Yeah I followed the guide. I'm trying my hand at building a GitHub integration, so the key is for GitHub.

Comment: Can you add your procfile ?

Comment: Procfile added.

Answer (score 2):

Your app need to start listening to the port defined in the env. For example if you have an expressjs app it should look something like this:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send("Hello world"))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

If the app does not bind to the correct port, heroku is going to consider the app unhealthy and will terminate it.

You need to see this line in the logs, which indicates that heroku recognized the app as healthy:

```
State changed from starting to up
```

Keep in mind that this port thing is a special requirement for the `web` process. The other processes in your app does not have such a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Try 2 things:
Change your procfile:

```
web: node start.js
```

Then make sure that your web process it running by scaling it up:

```
heroku ps:scale web=1
```

On your computer in a terminal window run this command in your project:

```
heroku local web
```

It simulates how Heroku runs your app and should give you information of what is happening.

Comment: Tried it but no luck... Changed Procfile to be 'node bin/app' + scaled the app down & back up but it still crashes. If I somehow get it working myself I'll post it here.

Comment: My only advice is to use Heroku to start your app locally and see what it says (updated answer)